# Difference between a Byte, Word, Long and a Long Word?

Tags: memory, assembly, hardware

I'm aware that a Byte is 8 bits, but what do the others represent? I'm taking an assembly course which uses a Motorola 68k Architecture, and I'm confused on the vocabulary present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned on the first page of the [operator's manual for the 68k Architecture](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf), in your case a word is 16 bits and a long word is 32 bits.

In an assembly language, a word is the CPU's natural working size. Each instruction, as well as addresses in memory, tend to be one word in length. Whereas a byte is always 8 bits, the size of a word depends on the architecture you're working in.

Comment: In addition it’s worth noting that the [byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of words and longs in the 68K are opposite the ubiquitous i386 and x86_64 CPUs.